htaccess how to catch root index call
I have a .htaccess in the website root that needs to catch all .php pages and redirect them somewhere.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/notice.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$ 
RewriteRule $ /notice.php [R,L]

This works fine, but it fails when the website default root is called (default root is index.php).
So; https://www.website.com/index.php --> successfully redirects to notice.php
but https://www.website.com/ does not, thus instead shows the contents of the index.php page.
Things I have tried:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/notice.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/$
RewriteRule $ /notice.php [R,L]

This doesn't work.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/notice.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*$
RewriteRule $ /notice.php [R,L]

This doesn't work either.
How can I set the .htaccess to catch the default index loader when the root folder filename is unspecified? I can not use DirectoryIndex notice.php because this redirect is time sensitive (only applies at certain dates and times).
eg
RewriteCond %{TIME} >=20241130230000
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/notice.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.$
RewriteRule $ /notice.php [R,L]


Instead of RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/$ use RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$

As Soon as I posted this question I found the answer;
Thanks Stack Overflow for forcing me to work through to the solution:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Setting the criteria to be "if not a file" which is the default for "..../" requests.
so;
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/notice.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule $ /notice.php [R,L]

Works!
